# Java: Reading and Reading/Writing to a file via multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

I am a newcomer to Java threads and I have a situation where I must continuously read from a file and also in a separate operation read and edit the same file(not continuously but at any random time). I understand this is a situation that can benefit from the use of multiple threads. How do I set up this situation so that both processes can take place together. I have the following code which is not thread-enabled :

Continuously reading segment(assume that `readFile` method has the code to read a file line-by-line):

```
public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        AlertsMonitor monitor = new AlertsMonitor();
        try {
            while(true)
                monitor.readFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the following method may execute at any time:

```
public void searchUser(String user)
{
        new FileSearcher().searchUser(user); //Search for the supplied string 
                                             //inside the same file
}
```

Both methods work on the same file. Thanks for any help !

Comment: Dangerous. You cannot open two streams for the same file at same time, you will need to share a unit stream between threads. I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way to open/close stream every time a thread access the file ?

Comment: Yes. But imagine a situation that one thread have to wait another thread to finish his operations. So, at the end, it will be a serial communication, not a parallel, as you want. My suggestion is to create a class to handle everythink that will occur in a file and ensure that every operation at the file will be done by this class in a single thread. I am not sure, but I believe that all database works at this way. Intead of creating multiples thread, just create an exclusive thread for working with this file.

Comment: What's the relationship between the reading and the editing?

Comment: For the second process, I can look up a user(as shown) or add a user(which is basically editing the file). First process continues to read the file and doing some operation.